# Error adding a controller - Unable to resolve service for type -.NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am new to .net 6 and running through a tutorial.

I get to adding a api controller with actions using Entity Framework. Specify my Model Class and my Data Context class but i keep getting an error.

"Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions[OdeToFood.Data.OdeToFoodDbContext] while attempting to active 'OdeToFood.Data.OdeToFoodDbContext"

My model is

```
    public class Restaurant
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(80)]
        public string Name{ get; set; }=string.Empty;

        [Required, StringLength(255)]
        public string Location { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public CuisineType? Cuisine { get; set; }
    }
```

and my DBContext is

```
public class OdeToFoodDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Restaurant> Restaurants { get; set; }

        public OdeToFoodDbContext(DbContextOptions<OdeToFoodDbContext> options) : base(options) 
        {

        }

    }
```

my program.cs has

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<OdeToFoodDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("OdeToFoodDb"));
});
```

and my nuget packages are below
https://ibb.co/P1ZVmc3

Is it weird that the autogenerated is 6.0.11 while all others are 6.0.12?

Any help would be much appreciated. Have spent a whole day trying to figure this out and have tried multiple things like clearing the nuget cache, installing different nuget versions.

Comment: "Is it weird that the autogenerated is 6.0.11 while all others are 6.0.12?" My project is too.

Comment: Make sure you add it to the services before calling `var app = builder.Build();`  Do you add your OdeToFoodDbContext in your   api controller ?

Comment: I call var app = builder.Build(); afterwards. I selected the OdeToFoodDbContext when i went to create the controller, this is where i got the error.

Comment: Could you share your ConnectionString ?

Comment: "ConnectionStrings": {
    "OdeToFoodDb": "Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectModels;Initial Catalog=OdeToFood;Integrated Security=True"
  }

Answer (score 0):

First change the configuration binding . Call configuration from the dependency container

```
//In the method constructor
IConfiguration configuration

//In the UseSqlServer method
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<OdeToFoodDbContext>(options =>
{
   options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("OdeToFoodDb"));
});
```

Then in the Controller/Service call the Context from the dependency container
(best practice is to use it in the service, then use the service in the controller)

```
private readonly OdeToFoodDbContext  context;

public Controler/Service(OdeToFoodDbContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

//Use the context
var result = this.context //.....
```